# Regex to replace all non numbers but allow a '+' prefix

Tags: regex, kotlin

I want to delete all invalid letters from a string which should represent a phone number. Only a '+' prefix and numbers are allowed.
I tried in Kotlin with

```
"+1234abc567+".replace("[^+0-9]".toRegex(), "")
```

It works nearly perfect, but it does not replace the last '+'.
How can I modify the regex to only allow the first '+'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a regex replacement on the following pattern:

```regex
(?<=.)\+|[^0-9+]+
```

Sample script:

```java
String input = "+1234abc567+";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=.)\\+|[^0-9+]+", "");
System.out.println(input);   // +1234abc567+
System.out.println(output);  // +1234567
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
(?<=.)\+  match a literal + which is NOT first (i.e. preceded by >= 1 character)
|         OR
[^0-9+]+  match one or more non digit characters, excluding +
```

Comment: Works like a charm in my code, thank you.

Comment: Looks even shorter if we can use **\d** instead of **0-9** in there :). Excellent solution nonetheless

Comment: @SandeepGusain For various reasons, I prefer putting `0-9` into a character class rather than `\d`, because it lends to character classes that are easier to read IMHO.

Comment: @SandeepGusain This can be written much shorter, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66474656/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(\+)|\D+
```

Replace with the backreference to the first group, `$1`. See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tGXEAu/1).

*Details*:

- `^(\+)` - a `+` at the start of string captured into Group 1
- `|` -  or
- `\D+` - one or more non-digit chars.

**NOTE**: a raw string literal delimited with `"""` allows the use of a single backslash to form regex escapes, such as `\D`, `\d`, etc. Using this type of string literals greatly simplifies regex definitions inside code.

See the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/HWQW35896):

```kotlin
val s = "+1234abc567+"
val regex = """^(\+)|\D+""".toRegex()
println(s.replace(regex, "$1"))
// => +1234567
```

Comment: @SandeepGusain I mentioned that `$1` is a backreference to the first group, Group 1. `\+` is wrapped with parentheses that form a [*capturing* group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). To use that value inside a replacement pattern, a `$`+the group ID is used. Numbering starts with `1` (since `$0` is a backreference to the whole  match value).

Comment: Very interesting solution. I am always stunned by the power of regex ;)